# Can't Connect to UI object button

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

i have to use 2 form in one python application.I'm loading my UI file in QWidget Class.I must to overload Qwidget close event because when i close the first form then i must terminate application.In this way i cant connect to UI object like button.

I searched some examples in the web but i didnt find any solution.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MainForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def _init_(self):
        super(MainForm, self)._init_()

        QUiLoader().load('ui/mainform.ui', self)

        self.btn_print.clicked.connect(self.print) #THROW ERROR

        self.show()
        self.secondForm = SecondForm()

    def print(self):
        print('asd')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        sys.exit()

class SecondForm(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def _init_(self):
        super(SecondForm, self)._init_()
        self.show()

if _name_ == '_main_':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

AttributeError: 'MainForm' object has no attribute 'btn_print'

Comment: change `QUiLoader().load('ui/mainform.ui', self)` to `self.ui = QUiLoader().load('ui/mainform.ui', self)` and `self.ui.btn_print.clicked.connect(self.print)`

Comment: it worked.thank you.